# Minimize the Height of the Vertical Gallery items? Gallery "Templatesize" property Vs Gallery item "Height" property

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas, power-platform

We have a Vertical Gallery inside containers, as follow:

[image: johnjohn123_0-1697640840269.png]

now each gallery's item is occupying a lot of vertical space, as follow:

[image: johnjohn123_1-1697640980331.png]

so how I can minimize this space in a dynamic way? now there are 2 settings I can change:

1. Gallery's TemplateSize =104:

[image: johnjohn123_2-1697641194145.png]

2. Gallery's Item Height =200 :

[image: johnjohn123_3-1697641228772.png]

so which property I need to change? and can I define dynamic formulas instead of defining hard-coded numbers inside those 2 properties?

Comment: Did you try below solution? Is it working for you?

Comment: @GaneshSanap-MVP thanks i check it, but i am trying to find a more straightforward approach instead of hardcoding the height

Comment: With the examples I gave below, it is not hardcoding the fixed height. Examples are for dynamic height based on heights of all controla inside the gallery. I don't there is any other way than this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the`TemplateSize` property of Power Apps gallery control to manage the height of individual item inside the gallery.

And yes, you can define the dynamic formulas for these properties.

**Example**:

You have a horizontal separator control (named `recSeparator`) at the bottom to gallery template, you can try setting TemplateSize property to:

```
recSeparator.X + recSeparator.Height + 10
```

If it does not work for you, you can try  adding all controls inside the gallery template to formula like:

```
label1.X + label1.Height + 5 + recSeparator.X + recSeparator.Height + 10
```

Where 5 is space between two controls.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the Flexible Height gallery. Each individual row in your gallery will automatically resize based on the content of the row.

[image]

For example, the template height is 220 for the image below

[image]

When you go to play mode you will see that the template will resize itself

[image]